# How to prevent tagline text from overlapping all other content?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This is probably a really basic question, but my tagline on my `Bootstrap` template overlaps all other content.

For instance, if I scroll down the page and my logo passes through the text, the text will lay on top of the logo. This is also the case with the navbar, the text will lay over the navbar as I scroll down the page and it's especially apparent on smaller screen sizes.

I tried adjusting the z-index, but the text completely disappears when I position the elements. 
Here are some code snippets (thanks in advance for any help):

```
HTML (h1 headers are the issue)
    <span id="index.html">
        <section class="creative-banner">
            <div  data-nav-dots="false" data-nav-arrow="true" data-items="1" data-sm-items="1" data-lg-items="1" data-md-items="1" data-autoplay="true">
                <div class="item"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/home.jpg" alt="person sittng on bench">
                    <div class="creative-text text-left">
                        <h1 class="iq-font-white iq-mt-10"><strong>Go Ahead, Share Your Idea <br>With The World</br></strong></h1> <!--Original class = "text-uppercase iq-font-white display-3"-->
                        <h1 class="iq-font-white iq-mt-10"><strong>We'll Help</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS: .

```
owl-item.active .creative-text.text-left h1 { animation: 1s .2s fadeInRight both; }
```

Comment: You could add your Bootstrap template to the question.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Most probably you don't need any custom css because in Bootstrap 4 almost everything can be done using native Bootstrap classes alone. Post the complete code you used so we can see what's wrong there.

Comment: try adding the code you are using for others to troubleshoot what is causing the problem or at least a live link to the page

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in adding a link to my site so you can see the code, I've added a Github link. Again, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Got it, I'll add a few code snippets of specific areas I've been working on. Thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and added the lines of HTML and CSS I've been working with.

Comment: That tiny code snippet is useless. You need to add **testable** code for the entire thing. How hard can it be after @j08691 has pointed out exactly what you need to do?? What I can already see from that tiny, non-complete and non-verifyable snippet is that you are using custom classes way too much and that certainly messes things up. No surprise. But for any real help you need to read the article linked by j08691, read it THREE TIMES and do what it says!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewed this issue and confirmed that the cause was the z-index. In the CSS, the index for the text was set to 999 and the header was 9. I edited the z-index for the header to 1000 and this corrected the issue.

CSS for header:
header { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; display: inline-block; width: 100%; z-index: 1000; padding: 25px 100px 0; background: #fff; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; }

CSS for Text:
.creative-text { position: absolute; top: 55%; left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); padding: 100px; z-index: 999; display: inline-block; width: 100%; }